# How to Hide the selected option in select dropdown list

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<ul><li>option1</li><li>option2</li><ul>
```

I'm using ul li for select dropdown. The value which has been selected should not be appeared in the drop down. I have code snippet in jsfiddle

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v363gkj6/

Any support on this.

Comment: *"should not be appeared"* does not make sense - Can you please clarify exactly what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: please post your JS/jQuery code too.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try this:

```
// Iterate over each select element
$('select').each(function() {

    // Cache the number of options
    var $this = $(this),
        numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

    // Hides the select element
   // $this.addClass('s-hidden');

    // Wrap the select element in a div
    $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');

    // Insert a styled div to sit over the top of the hidden select element
    $this.after('<div class="styledSelect"></div>');

    // Cache the styled div
    var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.styledSelect');

    // Show the first select option in the styled div
    $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

    // Insert an unordered list after the styled div and also cache the list
    var $list = $('<ul />', {
        'class': 'options'
    }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

    // Insert a list item into the unordered list for each select option
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
        $('<li />', {
            text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
            rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
        }).appendTo($list);
    }

    // Cache the list items
    var $listItems = $list.children('li');

    // Show the unordered list when the styled div is clicked (also hides it if the div is clicked again)
    $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('div.styledSelect .active').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.options').hide();
        });
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.options').toggle();
    });

    // Hides the unordered list when a list item is clicked and updates the styled div to show the selected list item
    // Updates the select element to have the value of the equivalent option
    $listItems.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
        $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
        $listItems.show();
        $(this).hide();
        $list.hide();
        /* alert($this.val()); Uncomment this for demonstration! */
    });

    // Hides the unordered list when clicking outside of it
    $(document).click(function() {
        $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
        $list.hide();
    });

});
```

I'm not sure if I get your question there but you may want to run it here http://jsfiddle.net/v363gkj6/1/

What I did is that I added a

```
$listItems.show();
$(this).hide();
```

from your code. Below is the code being modified:

```
$listItems.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
        $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
        $listItems.show();
        $(this).hide();
        $list.hide();
        /* alert($this.val()); Uncomment this for demonstration! */
    });
```

Comment: works fine. Thanks for your support.  How do i hide the first element which is selected when we refresh.

I'm trying this code - $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).hide());

Comment: try add this code $(".select").find("li").eq(0).hide(); outside of the $("select")

Comment: I tried.. $("select").find("li").eq(0).hide(); Unable to hide it.

Comment: It should be $(".select") not $("select")

Comment: Misplaced it. Now it works fine. Thanks for your support Neil.